# How to Recursively Append Child Objects to Parent Objects By Key

Tags: javascript, object, recursion

I have a flat object structure which outlines which objects have parents and which don't. I'm now at the point that I need it to be formatted in the correct structure so I can loop through it and perform functions.

Just to add before I go into detail.. I know the Object structure is not consistent, I'm still working on making sure all individual items are consistent. The most important part is that children are aligned with parents.

I've searched online, but couldn't seem to find anything that fit my exact need. The structure, whether good or bad, is what I'm stuck with now.

I was fiddling with this code which does loop and append children to the appropriate parent, and removes the old key. I forgot about recursion and can't wrap my head around doing this... in this specific case.

```
var tree = hierarchy.tree, key;
for (key in tree) {
  if (tree.hasOwnProperty(key)) tree[key].children = {};
}
iterate();
return tree;

function iterate() {
  var field, node;
  for (field in tree) {
    if (tree.hasOwnProperty(field)) {
      node = tree[field];
      if (node.parent !== undefined) {
        tree[node.parent].children[field] = node;
        delete tree[field];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the base structure:

```
var tree = {
  "submit": {
    "order": 0,
    "field": "submit"
  },
  "hc3qu2nf4": {
    "label": "title",
    "parent": "",
    "order": 0,
    "field": "title",
    "options": {
      "Font Size": "25px",
      "Font Weight": "Bold",
      "Font Style": "Italic",
      "Color": "rgb(64, 128, 128)"
    }
  },
  "dhthivju9": {
    "label": "divider",
    "parent": "",
    "order": 1,
    "field": "divider",
    "options": {
      "height": "14px",
      "color": "#21ce09",
      "width": "50%"
    }
  },
  "z5o9m7sgx": {
    "label": "",
    "parent": "4hhsi94n7",
    "order": 0,
    "field": "col"
  },
  "85ugwci2c": {
    "label": "",
    "parent": "4hhsi94n7",
    "order": 1,
    "field": "col"
  },
  "4hhsi94n7": {
    "label": "column",
    "parent": "",
    "order": 2,
    "field": "column"
  },
  "sbf0bg1o7": {
    "label": "month",
    "parent": "z5o9m7sgx",
    "order": 0,
    "field": "month",
    "options": {
      "start": "2019-04"
    },
    "required": true
  },
  "c3bwnyjmg": {
    "label": "",
    "parent": "4hhsi94n7",
    "order": 2
  },
  "n5m9d84dg": {
    "label": "number",
    "parent": "85ugwci2c",
    "order": 0,
    "field": "number",
    "options": {
      "start": "5",
      "min": "5",
      "max": "10",
      "step": "2"
    }
  },
  "krfxfnzsr": {
    "label": "date",
    "parent": "c3bwnyjmg",
    "order": 0,
    "field": "date",
    "options": {
      "start": "2019-05-03"
    }
  }
}
```

Ideally I would like the structure to be like this below. There could be multiple more layers than this.

```
{
  "submit": {
    "order": 0,
    "field": "submit"
  },
  "hc3qu2nf4": {
    "label": "title",
    "parent": "",
    "order": 0,
    "field": "title",
    "options": {
      "Font Size": "25px",
      "Font Weight": "Bold",
      "Font Style": "Italic",
      "Color": "rgb(64, 128, 128)"
    }
  },
  "dhthivju9": {
    "label": "divider",
    "parent": "",
    "order": 1,
    "field": "divider",
    "options": {
      "height": "14px",
      "color": "#21ce09",
      "width": "50%"
    }
  },
  "4hhsi94n7": {
    "label": "column",
    "parent": "",
    "order": 2,
    "field": "column",
    "children": {
      "z5o9m7sgx": {
        "label": "",
        "order": 0,
        "field": "col",
        "children": {
          "sbf0bg1o7": {
            "label": "month",
            "parent": "z5o9m7sgx",
            "order": 0,
            "field": "month",
            "options": {
              "start": "2019-04"
            },
            "required": true
          }
        }
      },
      "85ugwci2c": {
        "label": "",
        "order": 1,
        "field": "col",
        "children": {
          "n5m9d84dg": {
            "label": "number",
            "parent": "85ugwci2c",
            "order": 0,
            "field": "number",
            "options": {
              "start": "5",
              "min": "5",
              "max": "10",
              "step": "2"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "c3bwnyjmg": {
        "label": "",
        "order": 2,
        "children": {
          "krfxfnzsr": {
            "label": "date",
            "parent": "c3bwnyjmg",
            "order": 0,
            "field": "date",
            "options": {
              "start": "2019-05-03"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**In addition, it could be great if I could maintain the appropriate "order" of each item, so they are sorted appropriately.**

---

**UPDATE**
I'm not married to the output structure. If someone has a better idea please let me know.

Comment: If you need an ordered collection, use arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this solution but it uses arrays instead of objects (for `find`, `reduce`, `splice`, `push`, etc...) so the final output is not exactly what you wanted, but you wrote it was not set in stone.

```js
const data = {
  "submit": {
    "order": 0,
    "field": "submit"
  },
  "hc3qu2nf4": {
    "label": "title",
    "parent": "",
    "order": 0,
    "field": "title",
    "options": {
      "Font Size": "25px",
      "Font Weight": "Bold",
      "Font Style": "Italic",
      "Color": "rgb(64, 128, 128)"
    }
  },
  "dhthivju9": {
    "label": "divider",
    "parent": "",
    "order": 1,
    "field": "divider",
    "options": {
      "height": "14px",
      "color": "#21ce09",
      "width": "50%"
    }
  },
  "z5o9m7sgx": {
    "label": "",
    "parent": "4hhsi94n7",
    "order": 0,
    "field": "col"
  },
  "85ugwci2c": {
    "label": "",
    "parent": "4hhsi94n7",
    "order": 1,
    "field": "col"
  },
  "4hhsi94n7": {
    "label": "column",
    "parent": "",
    "order": 2,
    "field": "column"
  },
  "sbf0bg1o7": {
    "label": "month",
    "parent": "z5o9m7sgx",
    "order": 0,
    "field": "month",
    "options": {
      "start": "2019-04"
    },
    "required": true
  },
  "c3bwnyjmg": {
    "label": "",
    "parent": "4hhsi94n7",
    "order": 2
  },
  "n5m9d84dg": {
    "label": "number",
    "parent": "85ugwci2c",
    "order": 0,
    "field": "number",
    "options": {
      "start": "5",
      "min": "5",
      "max": "10",
      "step": "2"
    }
  },
  "krfxfnzsr": {
    "label": "date",
    "parent": "c3bwnyjmg",
    "order": 0,
    "field": "date",
    "options": {
      "start": "2019-05-03"
    }
  }
};

function sortArray(orderedArray, remainingArray) {
  if(remainingArray.length === 0) {
    return orderedArray;
  }
  else {
    remainingArray.forEach((remainingItem, index) => {
      if(orderedArray.find(x => x.identifier === remainingItem.parent)) {
        orderedArray.push(remainingItem);
        remainingArray.splice(index, 1);
      }
    });
    return sortArray(orderedArray, remainingArray);
  }
}

function insertNode(tree, node) {
  if(!tree) return;
  let item = tree.find(x => x.identifier === node.parent);
  if(item) {
    (item.children || (item.children = [])).push(node);
  } else {
    tree.forEach(x => {
      insertNode(x.children, node);
    });
  }
  return tree;
}

function createTree(data) {
  let tempArray = [];

  for (let key in data) {
    tempArray.push({ ...data[key], identifier: key });
  }
  
  tempArray = sortArray(tempArray.filter(x => !x.parent), tempArray.filter(x => x.parent));

  return tempArray.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
    if(currentValue.parent === "") {
      accumulator.push(currentValue);
    } else {
      insertNode(accumulator, currentValue);
    }
    return accumulator;
  }, []);
}

console.log(createTree(data));
```

Comment: It's probably for the best I migrate to arrays. This is great, one thing I found was after returning the tempArray it wasn't always sorted by the order key. So I added a `return tempArray.sort(function(a, b) {
      return a.order - b.order;
    });`

Answer (score 0):

The example below preserves `Object` type instead of switching to `Array`. See inline comments for more details. Basic concept is to treat the tree itself as a master branch and iterate through branches until finding the parent to reposition the child to.

```js
//iterating through an object/array that's changing can cause unexpected results
//iterate through a duplicate that will not change
let tree = {
    "submit": {
      "order": 0,
      "field": "submit"
    },
    "hc3qu2nf4": {
      "label": "title",
      "parent": "",
      "order": 0,
      "field": "title",
      "options": {
        "Font Size": "25px",
        "Font Weight": "Bold",
        "Font Style": "Italic",
        "Color": "rgb(64, 128, 128)"
      }
    },
    "dhthivju9": {
      "label": "divider",
      "parent": "",
      "order": 1,
      "field": "divider",
      "options": {
        "height": "14px",
        "color": "#21ce09",
        "width": "50%"
      }
    },
    "z5o9m7sgx": {
      "label": "",
      "parent": "4hhsi94n7",
      "order": 0,
      "field": "col"
    },
    "85ugwci2c": {
      "label": "",
      "parent": "4hhsi94n7",
      "order": 1,
      "field": "col"
    },
    "4hhsi94n7": {
      "label": "column",
      "parent": "",
      "order": 2,
      "field": "column"
    },
    "sbf0bg1o7": {
      "label": "month",
      "parent": "z5o9m7sgx",
      "order": 0,
      "field": "month",
      "options": {
        "start": "2019-04"
      },
      "required": true
    },
    "c3bwnyjmg": {
      "label": "",
      "parent": "4hhsi94n7",
      "order": 2
    },
    "n5m9d84dg": {
      "label": "number",
      "parent": "85ugwci2c",
      "order": 0,
      "field": "number",
      "options": {
        "start": "5",
        "min": "5",
        "max": "10",
        "step": "2"
      }
    },
    "krfxfnzsr": {
      "label": "date",
      "parent": "c3bwnyjmg",
      "order": 0,
      "field": "date",
      "options": {
        "start": "2019-05-03"
      }
    }
  },
  tree2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(tree)); //clone, not reference

console.log(tree === tree2); //test to confirm duplicate is not a reference

function reposition_child(parent, child, node, branch) {
  //check if the parent exists in this branch
  if (branch.hasOwnProperty(parent)) {
    let bp = branch[parent];
    //create children object as needed
    if (!bp.hasOwnProperty('children')) {
      bp.children = {};
    }
    //transplant the node as a child
    bp.children[child] = node;
    return true;
  } else {
    //iterate through the branches with children looking for the parent
    let found = false;
    for (let sub_branch in branch) {
      if (branch[sub_branch].hasOwnProperty('children')) {
        found = reposition_child(parent, child, node, branch[sub_branch].children);
      }
      //exit the loop once the parent is found
      if (found) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}

//iterate through the tree (duplicate fixed version)
for (let node in tree2) {
  let tn = tree2[node];
  //reposition nodes that have a non-empty parent
  if (tn.hasOwnProperty('parent') && tn.parent.length) {
    reposition_child(tn.parent, node, tn, tree);
    delete tree[node];
  }
}

//cleanup and output
delete tree2;
console.log(tree);
```

Comment: By writing `let tree = tree2 = {...}` you're just creating two references on the same object. Demo : `let tree = tree2 = {test: 'test'}; //tree === tree2;` `let tree3 = {test: 'test'}; let tree4 = {test: 'test'}; //tree3 !== tree4`

Comment: @YoukouleleY, thanks. Updated to clone instead of reference.

Comment: thanks but I realized after viewing @YoukouleleY 's answer, the only way to sort is to switch to arrays. If it wasn't for maintaining order, this would fit my needs!